# In Visual Studio 2019, unable to set physicalPath for web app debug

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express

VS 2019 problem.

I'm trying to debug an ASP.NET website by launching it in IIS Express locally. The problem is that in *applicationhost.config*, the *physicalPath* parameter is set automatically to my project's source folder, not the deploy folder. On every build, *applicationhost.config* file gets recreated, ignoring my changes. I cannot find any place in the project's Build, Web or Package Publish/Web settings in VS to set the website's physical path.

Is there any way to modify the *physicalPath* when debugging in VS? Preferably setting different paths for different build configurations.

Comment: VS/IIS Express integration was designed that way ("the physicalPath parameter is set automatically to my project's source folder"), so that VS can fully control the settings.  Why do you want to make changes there?

Comment: 1. So I can have separate release/debug/etc build folders, each of them debuggable locally.
2. So I can move the deploy folder outside of the source folder, i.e. out of Git visibility, and generally for clean separation between the source files and a deployable site.

Comment: Then you won't get that kind of things yet with VS, when it was designed in a different approach, https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3 My only advice is to find an alternative that won't conflict with VS, or more pains are ahead.